# Positioning circles in svg using d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

**Here is my condition**
I need to draw circles based on user's input ( the number of circles). 
I have a problem in placing those circles in the svg container.
My referral code is---http://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459
If I try placing more circles in the svg , the circles get transformed to the x and y co-ordinate supplied in the nodes array. How do I go about positioning as many circles as I want without hampering the usability and the ui of the container?

**Lets say this is my node array:-->**

```
nodes = [{title: "Activity1", id: 0, x: xLoc, y: yLoc},
         {title: "Activity2", id: 1, x: xLoc+200,y: yLoc},
         {title: "Activity3", id: 2, x: xLoc+400,y: yLoc},
         {title: "Activity4", id: 3, x: xLoc+600,y: yLoc},
         ];
```

This piece of code define the circles

```
thisGraph.circles=
                thisGraph.circles.data(thisGraph.nodes, function(d){ 
    console.log("Id of the circles"+d.id);
    return d.id;});
```

And this piece of code illustrates the placement of circle in the svg

```
var newGs= thisGraph.circles.enter()
          .append("g")
           .attr("transform", function(d){return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";});
```

The circles get transformed to d.x i.e xLoc and yLoc
The alternative i tried was using: Math.random * svgHeight for cx attribute and Math.random * svg Width for cy attribute. But the circles seemed to be scattered around rendering a scattered graph!. any help would be highly appreciated@!

Comment: Have you looked at using a force directed layout like the one shown in http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2706022? This ensures that the circles won't overlap if possible. There is more information at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout.

Comment: Yes I have looked at the forced layout too..But I want something like that of  #6863459 which can be modified accordingly to our usage like the number of circles we want. My aim is to make a data-driven graph editor.

Comment: The user should be able to add new nodes and edges!

Comment: You mean like this? http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347

Comment: Can you suggest any Graph Editor Libraries that can be used easily in any browser / mobile?

Comment: Even if it's d3.js, would you be able to say how to interact with the nodes of a graph editor and add additional attributes? suppose one node represents activity--> I want to add attributes like activity_name, start_date and end_date? How can I do it ? Should i go about using any database or just plain d3.js? I have tried using php, it seems to be very difficult to integrate both. I have put the attributes in the data array nodes and tried adding those attribute data using html text boxes, but i cant display them on the graph. how do i move data from php database and show it on the graph?